# Thoughts on Updating Disconnected Entity Graph

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I'm attempting to set-up a project to use disconnected entities and encapsulating my DbContext inside of a "Repository" class.  Each of the disconnected entities has a local property to track their state remotely and is parsed by the repository when it's passed in to set the EntityState property accordingly.

My question is pertaining to updating child objects in the object graph.  Should I set up the repository with update methods that take in commonly updated entities or should I have a single update method for the parent object in the object-graph and attach / update it.

For Example

```
public class Company {
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Department> { get; set; }
   public LocalEntityState LocalEntityState { get; set; }  // Enum for tracking disconnected changes 
}

public class Department {
   public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
   public Company Company { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
   public LocalEntityState LocalEntityState { get; set; }  
}

public class Employee {
   public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
   public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public Department Department { get; set; }
   public LocalEntityState LocalEntityState { get; set; }  
}
```

If I go with the single method to update the entire object graph for entities that are in the inserted/updated state, I can go with something like the following interface.  One caveat though, is that I need to always have a instance of company and department loaded if I'm going to make an update on employee.

```
public interface ICompanyRepository {
   void InsertOrUpdate(Company company)

   // Other methods for deletion, retrieval, etc..
}
```

Or I could use something like this where I'm providing methods for the "primary" objects that are changed in the DbContext.  This way I would only have to have an instance of Employee in memory if I wanted to edit/insert them.

```
public interface ICompanyRepository {
   void InsertOrUpdate(Company company);
   void InsertOrUpdate(Department department);
   void InsertOrUpdate(Employee employee);
}
```

I just want to get others thoughts on this and what the best route would be to avoid some common pitfalls.  For my actual project I've attempted to split the larger DbContext into a smaller subset of "Bounded Context" (From Julie Lerman's "Entity Framework in the Enterprise") so that each repository will be working with a set of related entities.  But I'm not sure on the best approach to updating these entities.  Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2):

In my view it's not a repository's responsibility to handle object graphs. That's something for a unit of work-like object.

A repository according to [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

These words *collection-like interface* are crucial. You access a repository as a collection of objects. So it has simple methods to get and add objects and that's it. In the past, I didn't distinguish well between repositories and services, so I always struggled with responsibilities. Now it's clear to me that services (domain services) handle use cases and repositories only exchange data in a predictable, generic way. Services, on the other hand, can expose a wide range of very different methods that represent the business processes.

Repositories *don't implement business logic*. So an `OrderRepository` doesn't have a method like `GetOpenOrders` because it doesn't have any notion of "Open"ness. Likewise, it doesn't have methods to deal with object graphs, because associations between objects are business concepts as well. (What I mean is that they don't have methods that in their signature accept or return objects other than the objects of which they represent the collection. They may return objects that contain other objects, but that's not their responsibility).

To be honest, I didn't fully grasp these concepts until I got acquainted with linq-to sql and later Entity Framework. These ORMs both offer perfect implementations of the generic repository pattern, `Table<T>` in L2S and `DbSet<T>` in EF (or the somewhat obsolete `ObjectSet`). It was a big surprise to me when I realized that these **repositories don't save data**.

But wait, they should "mediate between the domain and data", shouldn't they? Actually, no, they don't. Fowler says "between domain and *data mapping layers*". Ahhh. That's a big difference. The data mapping layer is the layer that does the actual data transfer from and to the data store.

So repositories can have methods like `Save`, or `Update`, but these do nothing but telling the mapping layer that an object should be marked as new or updated. They add objects to some context that may (or may not) save the objects into the data store later when the repository is long gone. In NHibernate this context is a `Session`, in EF it is a `DbContext`.

Soo... long story short. Your first implementation (only InsertOrUpdate Company) could be a repository, the second not.

Storing an object graph is a service method task that may involve multiple repositories and, usually, one context or unit of work. It's been said before, `DbSet` is a repository implementation and `DbContext` is a unit of work. You may decide that an additional repository/UoW layer on top of these is not even necessary.